# How to run many instances of Google Chrome in full screen on multi monitor system

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome, multiple-monitors

I need to run multiple instances of Google Chrome.
Each instance must run on different monitor in a multi monitor system (Windows OS)
but in full screen without any buttons or menus.

I tried several combination of switches but without luck

--start-fullscreen

--window-position=10,10 -window-size=800,600

--kiosk

--new-window

The Kiosk mode works but If I try to run the next instance it will go again on the 
primary screen.

Is there a way to run the Kiosk mode (preffered) or FullScreen mode 
of different Windowed Chrome instances in a multimonitor system ?

Probably if nothing works I would need to start each instance programmatically and 
send F11 keys to each window. This will work but it is some kind of hacking solution.

I am interested to know if there is some gracefull way to tell to Chrome "run this instance in a window in full screen or kiosk mode."

Comment: Unfortunately that solution doesn't work at all. The kiosk mode is not set after setting the position. The Chrome starts in a window mode.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure if I got you write. I just take my mouse left-click on one tab, hold the mouse button and pull this tab out of the existing chrome window. This create a new independent chrome window which can be moved to the second monitor screen.
I hope this is understandable.

Comment: This solution wouldn't work in situation described in the question.  I am worried about the quality of your answers.  You have published 25 answers in a single day.  A good amount of your answers have several downvotes, none of them have a upvote, if you continue down this route you can be prevent from answering questions.

Comment: [What is the policy on signatures and links in answers?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/52486)